# Reinitialize a Ruby object

Tags: ruby

I am wondering if I am implementing the reinitialization of a Ruby object correctly.

I have a class called `Clipboard` that holds folders and files. When creating a new clipboard object, it is always empty: there are no folders or files on it. I also have a `reset` method that clears all the folders and files from the clipboard.

At first my code looked liked this:

```
class Clipboard
  def initialize
    @folders = []
    @files = []
  end

  def reset
    @folders = []
    @files = []
  end
end
```

But the fact that `reset` and `initialize` are exactly the same annoyed me. Besides resetting a clipboard object is the same as reinitializing it. So I changed my code to:

```
class Clipboard
  def initialize
    @folders = []
    @files = []
  end

  def reset
    initialize
  end
end
```

This works, but I was wondering if it is the correct way of going about reinitializing my object? Are there any reasons why I should not be calling `initialize` from an instance method? Thanks!

Comment: I am basically with the answers given; not against them, but if I were to go along the lines you suggest above, I would go one step further and do `alias reset initialize` or even call `initialize` directly in stead of reset. To be precise with the wording in the answers, `initialize` is not a constructor. it is an instance method that is called by a constructor.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code smells to me as it doesn't seem like good practice to call the constructor from within the an instance. I would simply refractor it like so:

```
class Clipboard
  def initialize
    setup
  end

  def reset
    setup
  end

  private

  def setup
    @folders = []
    @files = []
  end
end
```

Comment: Got me by a minute... +1 for having the same idea

Comment: Thanks, it felt strange, but I couldn't come up with this solution myself.

Answer (score 2):

It works but is a little unconventional.  Most likely you will want to add more functionality to the constructor.  What might be better is to use a private method the actually zeroes out the arrays and then your intent will be more clear in the code:

```
class Clipboard
  def initialize
    [...]
    setup
    [...]
  end

  def reset
    setup
  end

  private

  def setup
     @folders, @files = [], []
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, also for suggesting this syntax `@folders, @files = [], []`. I will use it.